# iOS: cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called immediately after numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have my uitable data being populated for the current section inside `numberOfRowsInSection`. I then expect it to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so that I can use that data.

In my `numberOfRowsInSection` I am overwriting the data from the previous section. Doing `NSLog` it shows that `numberOfRowsInSection` runs for all 149 sections before the first `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called... Why?

I have removed calls to `reloadData` since I saw it was the issue for someone else here on stack overflow but that didn't resolve the issue.

Per Jim I am adding what I am doing.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    FMResultSet *appointmentResults = [[DataClass getDB] executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE date = ?",[self.appointmentDates objectAtIndex:section]];
    int rowCount = 0;
    while ([appointmentResults next]) {
        [tempArray addObject:[appointmentResults resultDict]];
        rowCount++;
    }
    self.appointments = tempArray;
    NSLog(@"Appointments: %@ - %i", [self.appointmentDates objectAtIndex:section], rowCount);
    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Parse the appointments for the current section and display them
}
```

Comment: @jostster Why does this make a difference for your application?

Comment: What you describe sounds odd. First, you shouldn't be overwriting anything in `numberOfRowsInSection`. It should only be returning an integer. More accurate details are probably needed. But I believe that once a UITableView kicks these delegate methods off, it intends to update something in its view. But it should only be asking about visible sections and rows.

Comment: @Jim I modified my OP to show what I'm doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a general sense, it's not very good practice to rely upon Apple calling your delegate functions in any particular pattern.

With UITableView in particular, it only will request data on a need-to-know basis. The UITableView has a greater need to know how many sections and rows there are in the entire table so that it can handle things like scrolling position and scrollbar size properly, while actual cell contents can be allowed to slide until they're about to enter the user's view.

You can't take a call to numberOfRowsInSection as implying anything more than that the system wants to know how many rows are in a section. :)

Comment: Good point... I forgot cellForIndexPath was called as the cell begins to enter view... This makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Its the behavior of UITableView.

It will load only those cells which are visible. To calculate it, it will ask number of rows for each sections before displaying them.

The cells which are not visible, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not get called initially. It will get called once user scrolls through it.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that uitableview caches that data so runs through once and gets everything

Answer (score 0):

It is how the `UITableView` class works..

Nothing to be shocked at..and you won't be able to change that..

Also 149 sections should not be loaded at once.. load them as the user scrolls..

Comment: So your saying numberOfRowsInSection runs for all sections before the first cell is added? I thought it ran cellForIndexPath right after numberOfRowsInSection for that section.

Comment: doesn't work that way..although i understand your project would have been simpler..like this.. but table view works this way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh/change your table you should change appropriate data in `model`, then call one of tableView's `[tableView reload....];` methods (depends on what exactly you're trying to change).

`UITableViewDelegate` methods (especially those returning number of rows, sections...) shouldn't do much more than their name says or you'll end up with a total mess of your table or possibly app crashing...

When you call `[tableView reload....];` your content-providing methods will get called and that's the place to provide, well, content.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same situation. i think the reason is that the heightof row  return by the table is 0.